# why $.isEmptyObject($('#id-does-not-exist-on-page')) returns false?

Tags: jquery

I'm  little confused by `jQuery.isEmptyObject method`.

`$.isEmptyObject([])` -> returns true

but

`$('#id-does-not-exist-on-page')` => []

`$.isEmptyObject($('#id-does-not-exist-on-page'))` returns false

why ?
thanks.

Comment: Does not work with jQuery objects. Try plain js object. `$.isEmptyObject($('#id-does-not-exist-on-page')[0])`

Comment: If you want to test for the existence of an element in the page use `length`, for example: `if ($("#element").length) { /* it exists */ };`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/),

> Check to see if an object is empty (contains no properties)

but,

`$('#id-does-not-exist-on-page')` still has properties.

`$('#id-does-not-exist-on-page').addClass('abra_ka_dabra')`  // valid

`[].addClass('abra_ka_dabra');`  // TypeError: Object has no method 'addClass'

So,

try this instead

`$.isEmptyObject($('#id-does-not-exist-on-page')[0])`

Answer (score 2):

According to the jQuery documentation ([isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)) :

> The argument should always be a plain JavaScript Object as other types
>   of object (DOM elements, primitive strings/numbers, host objects) may
>   not give consistent results across browsers

Answer (score 1):

because `$('#id-does-not-exist-on-page')` returns a selector that matches nothing not an empty object which would be `{}`